# Batch Faulty Prime Number Generator

Tags: batch-file

This is the code:

```
@echo off
title 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set a=2
set b=3
echo 2
goto c
:b
set /a b+=2
:c
:a
for %%G in (!a!) do (set /a d=%%G*%%G
if !d! gtr !b! call :d
set /a c=b%%%%G
if !c!==0 call :b)
:d
set a=!a! !b!
echo !b!
goto b

exit
```

The limit to this is 509 and when I remove the if statement pertaining the test value squared, if shortens the possible outcomes instead of making the code more efficient. Without the said if statement, the code calculates up to the 800s but with it, it is limited to 509. What can I do to bypass this restriction?

I tweaked the script here and there and recoded it to run better:

```
@echo off
title 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set a=3
set b=3
echo 2
echo 3
:a
set /a b+=2
for %%G in (!a!) do (set /a d=%%G*%%G
if !d! gtr !b! goto b
set /a c=b%%%%G
if !c!==0 goto a)
:b
set a=!a! !b!
echo !b!
goto a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is somewhat strange. A couple details about it:

- I don't understand why you use `call` command. Your code *never* execute an `exit`, so you may eliminate the `exit` at end and the *executed* code is exactly the same.
- You may use `goto` instead `call`. This way, there is no limit in the results (excepting the 32-bits limit maximum number)

**EDIT**: *Reply to the comment*

Well, I just said that a program code that execute `call` commands many times without a single `exit` is certainly not usual, but this is just my opinion!

The code below is your first same code with just the `call`s replaced by `goto`s and improved formating, like removing unused lines: the `a:` label and the last `exit`.

```
@echo off
title 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set a=2
set b=3
echo 2
goto c

:b
set /a b+=2

:c
for %%G in (!a!) do (
   set /a d=%%G*%%G
   if !d! gtr !b! goto :d
   set /a c=b %% %%G
   if !c!==0 goto :b
)

:d
set a=!a! !b!
echo !b!
goto b
```

I run this program and get an endless loop of output results, so I stopped it after a while. These are the last results:

```
251117
251143
251149
251159
251171
251177
251179
251191
251197
251201
251203
251219
251221
```

As I said before, the limit in these results is the maximum 32-bits number managed by `set /A` command.

Comment: Your answer is somewhat strange in that it is completely unconstructive, the exit is leftover from when I created the outline from another script and goto makes almost no difference it ends the script in the 700s.

Comment: @user3093536: I apologize if my answer bother you; that was not my intention. See the edit in my answer, please...

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set a=2
set b=3
echo 2
goto c
:d
set a=%a% %b%
echo %b%
IF "%a:~8100,1%"=="" GOTO b
echo %a%
echo at limit
GOTO :EOF
:b
set /a b+=2
:c
:a
for %%G in (%a%) do (
 set /a d=%%G*%%G
 if !d! lss 0 ECHO done&ECHO !a!&GOTO :eof
 if !d! gtr !b! GOTO d
 set /a c=b%%%%G
 if !c!==0 goto b
)
GOTO d
```

Your major problem is that you `CALL` your main routine within your main routine - either by directly calling **B** or calling **D** which simply goes to B, so it's effectively the same thing. There's a limit to the number of nested loops you can have, and you were reaching that limit.

With this routine, reaching `:d` records a new prime number in the list `a`, and if the number is not prime, `:b` to select a new number to test.

The entire block from `FOR` to its closing <kbd>)</kbd> is parsed at one time and there's a liit to the length of that 'line' (about 8,190 chars). I just used 8100 as a limit to the length of `a` to stop the batch cleanly.

Note that `!var!~ is only required after an environment variable is changed within a loop.

Checking that `!d!` is less than zero will not be reached (because you reach the line-length limit) but ensures that if the candidate value exceeds ~2^31 then the routine should stop.

If you want to extend this, you'd need to record the values in a different manner - possibly an array. You may then run into a total size limit for the environment and you'd then need to start saving the results to a file.

Comment: Is it possible for me to use a text file with a prime on each row in a for loop? As in: for %%G in (!file!) ?

Comment: Actually, I seemed to have fixed it. It is running smoothly and is exceeding my expectations! It calculated over 3000 in about 4 seconds, so I'll update my answer.